# XSLT for-each condition get elements based on element attribute value greater than 1

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm sorry if this is duplicated question. I will delete it if it is duplicated. I am trying to transform XML file like example below, where I want to get variant of the `sizes` where only `size` with `stock quantity > 1`(before that i have to sum up all stocks to get the total quantity to be able to write condition). I have been trying with `for-each`, but I'm not sure where I did a mistake or how to correctly write the condition.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<offer>
    <products>
        <product>
            <sizes>
                <size id="B" name="38" available="in_stock" priority="5">
                    <price/>
                    <stock id="5" quantity="1" available_stock_quantity="1" />
                    <stock id="4" quantity="0" available_stock_quantity="0" />
                </size>
                <size id="C" name="38" available="in_stock" priority="5">
                    <price/>
                    <stock id="5" quantity="45" available_stock_quantity="45" />
                </size>
                <size id="D" name="38" available="in_stock" priority="5">
                    <price/>
                    <stock id="5" quantity="43" available_stock_quantity="43" />
                    <stock id="4" quantity="1" available_stock_quantity="1" />
                    <stock id="2" quantity="22" available_stock_quantity="22" />
                </size>
                <size id="E" name="38" available="in_stock" priority="5">
                    <price/>
                    <stock id="5" quantity="20" available_stock_quantity="20" />
                    <stock id="4" quantity="1" available_stock_quantity="1" />
                    <stock id="2" quantity="4" available_stock_quantity="4" />
                </size>
            </sizes>
        </product>
    </products>
</offer>
```

I have tried with selecting with for-each in XSLT file like below:

```
<xsl:for-each select="sizes/size/stock[@quantity > '1']">
```

and to sum stocks with this line

```
<xsl:element name="stocks">
   <xsl:value-of select="sum(.//stock/@available_stock_quantity)"/>
</xsl:element>
```

The result i want to get:

```
<variants groupingAttribute="size">
    <variant>
        <id>C</id>
        <size>38</size>
        <stocks>45</stocks>
        <prices/>
    </variant>
    <variant>
        <id>D</id>
        <size>38</size>
        <stocks>66</stocks>
        <prices/>
    </variant>
    <variant>
        <id>E</id>
        <size>38</size>
        <stocks>25</stocks>
        <prices/>
    </variant>
</variants>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the expected result. Consider also removing irrelevant parts of code - see: [mcve].

Comment: Not sure what you want get but this seems to work on my side : select="offer/products/product/sizes/size/stock[@quantity gt '1']"

Comment: In your expected result I don’t see the sum of the stocks. If I understand it correctly D should be 75 and E  24. Could you clarify?

Comment: sorry i forgot to edit that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to get variant of the `sizes` where only `size` with `stock quantity > 1`

I am not sure I understand this condition. if you mean that you want to include a `size` only when at least one of its `stock` children has a `quantity` that is greater than 1, then this should be quite simple:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/offer">
    <variants groupingAttribute="size">
        <xsl:for-each select="products/product/sizes/size[stock/@quantity > 1]">
            <variant>
                <id>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
                </id>
                <size>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
                </size>
                <stocks>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(stock/@quantity)" />
                </stocks>
                <prices/>
            </variant>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </variants> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```